# SQL Server formatting negative values from selected data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to stackoverflow but I do search it often.

I am creating a report from data in which I have to format negative numbers like,

```
-00000010  (9 characters max)
```

I am getting this,
000000-10

This is what I am attempting now but I'm having issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 'H' 
    + DG.BLOCK 
    + LEFT(DG.ZIP,5) 
    + RIGHT('000000000' 
    + CAST(CAST(SUM(DG.WP)AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9) 
    + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUM(DG.WE)AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9)
    + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUM(DG.EP)AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9) 
    + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUM(DG.EE)AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9)
    + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST(COUNT(DGG.CLAIMCONTROL)AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9)
    + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUM(DGG.INC) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9)
    + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUM(DGG.PAID)AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9)
    + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUM(DGG.ALAE) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(9)),9) 
AS [H Record]
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2012+, you have the option of Format().

**Example**

```
Select replace(format(-1,' 000000000'),'- ','-')
```

**Returns**

```
-000000001  If number was negative
 000000001  If number was positive
```

Just a word of caution.  Format() has some great functionality, but is not known to be a high performer.

Comment: Thank you John, not all my values are negative. I should have been more clear. If the value is not negative I need to display 000000001 if it is negative I need to show -000000001. I have about 12K rows that im working with and not sure how I would incorporate the format() function. Any sample code I can review?

Comment: Thank you John, I could not wrap my head around needing to add a negative value for each format. I ended up doing this. What do you think? Is there an easier way to do this?                                                                                          
+ case when SUM(DG.WP) < 0 then '-' else '0' end
+ RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CAST (CASE WHEN SUM(DG.WP)<0 THEN SUM(DG.WP)*-1 ELSE SUM(DG.WP) END AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)),8)

Comment: @DavidGomez I think you missed the point.  The example supplied would support any number positive or negative.  The -1 was just a sample value.  The value returned is a string and easy to concatenate...  Format()+Format()+Format()

Comment: @DavidGomez replace the -1 with your aggregate function.  No need to cast as INT either.

Comment: You are correct I missed the way the function would work . Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates formatting the data as either 9 digits plus an optional sign or as a fixed 9 characters including the sign.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample Int );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( -10 ), ( 100 ), ( -1000 );

-- Format the data.
select Sample,
  case when Sign( Sample ) = -1 then '-' else '' end +
    Right( Replicate( '0', 8 ) + Cast( Abs( Sample ) as VarChar(9) ), 9 ) as FormattedSample9PlusSign,
  case when Sign( Sample ) = -1 then
    '-' + Right( Replicate( '0', 7 ) + Cast( -Sample as VarChar(8) ), 8 ) else
    Right( Replicate( '0', 8 ) + Cast( Sample as VarChar(9) ), 9 ) end as FormattedSample9
  from @Samples;
```

Tip: In SSMS use *query results to text* (Ctrl-T) for more convenient display.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if you do not have v2012+:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SomeNumber INT);
DECLARE @padWidth INT=3;
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES(-1000),(-500),(-1),(0),(1),(500),(1000);

SELECT CASE WHEN m.SomeNumber < 0 THEN '-' ELSE ' ' END 
     + REPLACE(STR(ABS(m.SomeNumber),@padWidth),' ','0')
FROM @mockup AS m;
```

Numbers, which are to big, will be returned as `***`. This is better than other approaches cutting the string with `RIGHT` or `LEFT`. They might return a bad result...

This is returned

```
-***
-500
-001
 000
 001
 500
 ***
```

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 this works to get a number of 15 digits including the sign:

```
CASE WHEN MYNUMBER < 0 THEN '-'  ||   LPAD(MYNUMBER , 14, 0) 
                       ELSE LPAD(MYNUMBER , 15, 0)                                   
END
```